# Typescript, extended properties will only reflect on .map

Tags: typescript, types, array.prototype.map

I have a type `GetAllNegoRequestResponseItem` and `{ expiry: any }`. They are both combined using `&` as seen below

```
negotiations: (GetAllNegoRequestResponseItem & { expiry: any }[]) | undefined
```

To detail the title, negotiations is an array type of those things mentions that are combined or **undefined**, when

```
negotiations?.map((nego) => nego.iAmLookingPropertiesFromGetAllNegoReq...)
```

`nego` turns to a type `{ expiry: any }`

[image]

Not the expected combined properties anymore.

This is the mapped data of negotiations

[image]

[image]

I don't know if I misuse the Types.

Comment: No [mre] present, so impossible to give a definite answer, but shouldn't that be `(GetAllNegoRequestResponseItem & { expiry: any })[] | undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that

`negotiations: (GetAllNegoRequestResponseItem & { expiry: any }[]) | undefined`,

should be

`negotiations: (GetAllNegoRequestResponseItem & { expiry: any })[] | undefined`

**from }[]) to })[]** only close parenthesis away.

Anyway thank you